# PHP: a good way to universalize paths across OSs (slash directions)

Tags: php, path, operating-system

My simple concern is being able to handle paths across OSs, mainly in the regard of back and forward slashes for directory separators.

I was using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, however:

1. It's long to write
2. **Paths may come from different sources, not necessarily controlled by you**

I'm currently using:

```
    function pth($path)
    {
        $runningOnWindows = (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN');
        $slash = $runningOnWindows ? '\\' : '/';
        $wrongSlash = $runningOnWindows ? '/' : '\\' ;
        return (str_replace($wrongSlash, $slash, $path));
    }
```

Just want to know that there is nothing existing in the language that I'm reinventing,

Is there already an inbuilt PHP functon to do this?

Comment: There is the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant that holds the current OS's separator. It will help you because you don't need to check `runningOnWindows`. You just need to make your function convert all kinds of slashes *except* the one defined in `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> I'm aware of DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
>
> However: 1. It's long to write

Laziness is never a reason for anything

```
$path = (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR === '\\')
      ? str_replace('/', '\\', $subject)
      : str_replace('\\', '/', $subject);
```

or

```
$path = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
```

This will in one step replace "the right one" with itself, but that doesnt make any difference.

If you know for sure, that a path exists, you can use [realpath()](http://php.net/realpath)

```
$path = realpath($path);
```

However, that is not required at all, because every OS understands the forward slash `/` as a valid directory separator (even windows).

Comment: Hell, you can even mix slashes on Windows.  `'C:\Foo\Bar/baz/what.php'` is totally a legal path in PHP.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, there is really no reason to think about that. As far as I know there is exactly one exception, where it makes a difference on win http://php.net/domdocument.load Also the solution is mentioned there ;)

Comment: "you can even mix slashes on Windows". Here is one example when this didn't work on windows: exec("rd path\with/mixed/slashes") regarded the / as a key for the command

Comment: I dont know every pitfall on windows, but this topic is about a solution in php and a command executed via `exec()` has not that much to do with php.

Comment: @KingCrunch, You quoted him on "Laziness is never a reason for anything", but he definitely stated "Paths may come from different sources, not necessarily controlled by you" as the reason.

Comment: @Pacerier No, that was on "[DIRECTOR_SEPERATOR is] long to write". Sure, different sources _can_ be a problem, but read the entire answer. The easiest solution remains to use `/` always, because it is accepted by every OS. (There is one exception; something XMLish ... )

Comment: yes, "you can even mix slashes on Windows", but where that becomes problematic is when you are comparing paths... the slashes all have to be the same

Answer (score 6):

You are missing the [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) predefined constant.

Comment: Well, it's not enough for what he wants to do (Build a generic method to convert *any* path to the current OS's format). But it's a start

Comment: @Pekka: Sure. But he can lose the custom OS detection, which IMHO is the most unpleasant thing in that code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to pass those paths to standard PHP functions, you actually don't need to fix paths, as far as I can tell. Basic functions like `file_get_contents` or `fopen` work perfectly fine with any kind of path you throw at them.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change everything to forward slashes `/`. Get rid of back slashes `\` entirely. Forward slashes work on all OS's, including Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
  static function fx_slsh($path) {
    $path = str_replace(['/','\\'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    return substr($path, -1) == DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ? $path : $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  }
```

this one will also ensure there is a trailing slash

Comment: Linux is happy to see a trailing `/` when accessing a directory, but I'm not sure Windows would like that at all.

Comment: `fx_slsh($path)` ? Are vowels too expensive in this economy? `fix_slash($path)`